# Chrome auto-filling username into any eligible input that comes right before the password input

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

Autocomplete true|false, on|off no longer appears to be valid
Hiding in plain sight a text input, and password input before the legitimate one that needs to be accessible to the UI doesn't work. 
And dynamically clearing the input the username is put in isn't an option as we pre-populate that input on a number of legitimate reasons.

Also worth noting is it also appears that the input in question is populated by chrome despite being populated by what it should have been populated by.

Is there a clean solution for this behavior, as its rather problematic overall from a UX perspective.

Comment: If the field has to be populated by your code, can't you just set it to `readonly`?

Comment: Have you tried http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15738259/disabling-chrome-autofill?rq=1

Comment: Read Only wouldn't work as it is acceptable for the user to modify the input in question. We store the state if they ever changed it previously, and populate it for convenience. But all in all its changable

Comment: Trying the fake user/password inputs is something I currently try, and it worked for a while. It like autocomplete seems to not work anymore.